# "My answer is that I was asking the wrong question": Question Editing / Duplicate etiquette question

Tags: discussion

This relates to this question:

[Are NULL and 0 completely equivalent in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28717771/null-or-0-in-c-hard-restrictions)

In real life the interaction would have gone like this.

I face a problem which makes me uneasy to make some change, so I do some reading. Nothing seems to directly answer my question, so I go to a guru. I ask the guru my formulation of the question (omitting parts which are irrelevant). They offer me advice (and tell me that it has been asked many times before) and I go away and try to apply it. It doesn't help. At that point I realise I asked the wrong question. Not very wrong, just slightly wrong. That was also probably why the reading didn't help: I hadn't formulated my problem quite correctly. Probably all the reading of related but not quite the same questions didn't help, maybe I'd had a bad day, but whatever. So I ask again, with a slightly different question.

This seems to happen a lot in real life. (I'm sure it's not just me).

On SE just now I did something like this. I looked for duplicates before asking, asked a question, got some links for duplicates in comments, and some answers. I said sorry and thanks, went away, but it didn't help. Then I suddenly realised that I'd asked something slightly wrong, went back and edited the question.

Now, what I want to know is what the right thing is to do (and whether it was done) for me to treat the folk who contributed honourably (everyone did things in the right spirit, I think). The result is a page which is a bit of a mess. Some comments saying it's a dup, me agreeing then disagreeing, a modified question, two answers to the unmodified question, and marked as a dup which it may or may not be. Sitting round the sofa, this would have been a perfectly normal kind of interaciton, but the result here is chaos!

What I'm concerned about at this point is the page being in good shape for future visitors, and how I should handle situations like this in the future. I can't be the only person who realises that the answer to their question is that they're asking the wrong quesiton.

Comment: "Sitting round the sofa, this would have been a perfectly normal kind of interaction, but the result here is chaos!" Fantastic distillation of What Makes SO Different®!

Comment: Great story telling skills and analogy, a lot of things we're easier in real life than on the internet though

Comment: I've seen *much* messier questions than this, don't beat yourself up over it. Did the linked duplicate answer your question?

Comment: If you do go with the route of asking a new question, it helps deter negative reactions tremendously if you link the original question and explain why they are different.

Answer (score 48):

Generally speaking, the purpose of Stack Exchange is to have questions and answers as a reference for everyone. That this means getting *your* question answered is a useful side effect.

So within that context - the answer is 'whatever is most useful to everyone else'. Your original question may serve as a useful signpost for the next person who's thinking the same thing as you were. So even if you realise that you weren't asking the right question - leave it as is (or at least, keep edits 'cosmetic') and add *your own* answer explaining what you found. Including if relevant, links to duplicates, or the 'right' question.

And then you can accept it - an accepted answer doesn't mean it's *right*; it just means it's the one that helped most.

Future users find your question and follow the references. You get the answer you need. Everyone's happy. Resist the temptation to substantively change your original question, because by doing so - you make the (perfectly valid) answers now incorrect and misleading.

Comment: That certainly makes sense @Sobrique . I was going to do that but there was a link in the yellow box suggesting I edit the question to clarify it. The boundary between clarification and corerction is kind of blurred. To aid the use of SE as a reference, the best thing would be to delete the question: the meaning of the original is well covered elsewhere and having another subtly different one doesn't help. Modifying the question confuses the whole page. But then I was told that (understandably) the answerers may think that rude as tehri answers will go.

Comment: Clarifying a 'closed-as-dupe' is for when your question _isn't_ a dupe (and explaining why)

Comment: Oh drat. But surely things are rarely that clear cut most of the time? In this case it wasn't completely different, it could be seen as clarifying by being more specific and removing a misleading sentence, or it could be seen as a different question. Horses for courses really. I think I'd better stick to reading rather than contributing!

Comment: Nothing is ever 'clear cut'. But generally - it costs you nothing to ask another question if it's clearly distinct. I wouldn't worry about it too much - the fact that you're even considering it makes you a good person :)

Comment: Don't be afraid to ask a new question springing from the first, @DanSheppard. Just be careful and explicit about how they differ and what exactly is still unclear. Be prepared to need to edit the new question right away, in case people think you're asking the same thing again. If you have a someone who can read them over before you post, that's usually pretty helpful.

Answer (score 6):

It goes this way:

- You ask a question which has been asked many times before, so it gets closed as a duplicate.
- You aren't satisfied with the answers in the duplicate, but realize that if you edit your post you can clarify what makes your question different.
- BAM! Your question now automatically ends up in something called re-open review, where high rep users doing moderator duty can look through it and see if the changes are significant enough, then have it re-opened. For duplicates, it has to be someone who knows the specific topic, or they won't be able to tell.

---

As for this specific question, I've checked it and I happen to have the magic gold badge in the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag, which allows me to instantly close or open duplicates. A similar gold badge user was actually the one who closed the question.

And I agree with that user, this question should be closed as a duplicate, even after your changes. Among the duplicate answers there is a link to the excellent comp.lang C FAQ http://c-faq.com/null/index.html which happens to answer your question completely, before and after the edit.

Generally, I strongly recommend beginners and veterans alike to read that C FAQ, it is *the* C FAQ and in most cases of much better quality than the SO frequently asked questions.