# How do I proceed when a question received many answers, none satisfactory?

Tags: support

I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34018333/how-do-you-create-stateful-modular-self-contained-web-components-in-elm/34020861?noredirect=1#comment55810018_34020861). It has received 3 very informative answers that I read, understood and learned a lot from. But they do not answer the main motive of the question, which is implementing **modular** web components. They all implement web components, but which are not modular, because you can't insert them inside another component without the parent having awareness of the children implementation. The blame on this is on me, since the point wasn't very clear and I could've stressed it in a more specific way. Now I'm not sure how to proceed.

1. The answers are good by themselves. Deleting the question and asking again would hinder future visitors of such content, which seems unreasonable.
2. If I just edit the question, the current answers will look even more misplaced, and it is very unlikely that I'll get new answers since the thread is now old and won't show up on the main listing.
3. Just asking again would make my question an exact duplicate of the previous one.

Getting the actual answer for this question is important to me. How do I proceed.

Comment: Why can't you just bounty it?

Comment: Start by downvoting the answers if they're _not useful_.

Comment: There are existing metas that give useful etiquette tips. Example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286877/my-answer-is-that-i-was-asking-the-wrong-question-question-editing-duplicat

Answer (score 2):

Ask a new question.  Word it very clearly so that you don't repeat your previous mistake.  Make it abundantly clear how it's different from what you asked first time around.

But do NOT change your original question once you've got some answers.  There's nothing worse for people who are trying to help you than to have their correct answers invalidated, and possibly even downvoted, just because you changed your mind about what the question should be.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the question to make it clear what you want.  That will bump it to the front page which may get you more answers.  I would also leave comments for the existing answerers that you have edited the question and hope they can update their answer to address that.

Also, you could add a bounty to get attention.

No matter what you do, you need to make it clear what your problem is by editing your question or any new answers are just as likely as the old ones to not address your real problem.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like a great place to use [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties).

Per the description:

> In order to get good answers, you have to put effort into the question. Edit the question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer the question. This will naturally bump the question and get more people interested in it.
>
> However, if after doing this, you feel a particular question still isn't getting enough attention, adding a bounty may help.

The linked article continues with the benefits that bounties provide:

> What happens when I place a bounty?
>
> - The question is immediately bumped to the top of the active question list.
> - The question gets placed in the home page's featured tab for seven days.
> - The reputation you're using for the bounty is immediately and irreversibly deducted from your reputation.
> - If your new reputation brings you below the requirement for any privileges, you will lose access to those privileges.
>
> It is your responsibility to award the bounty during the seven-day period or the 24-hour grace period that follows it. You will receive several e-mail and site notifications as the bounty period draws to a close.

In short, a bounty will bump your question to the top of the active question list in order to garner it more attention. In addition, it will show up under [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/ending) bounties list screen as well exposing it to yet more users. Obviously there's no guarrantee that this will get your question answered, but it seems to be the next logical step in the progression of question asking so I'd start here.